# How return a setable const in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, constants, jsx

I try to write a function const who can return something like a const, bellow the goal.

```
const button_style = {
  width: "100px",
  height: "100px",
}
```

but where I can inject a modificable variable, but I don't find how write that in jsx. You can find bellow my differents fails. Is it possible ?

```
const set_button_style = () => {
  let w = 100
  let h = 100
  return ({ width: `${w}px`, height: `${h}px` });
}
```

```
const set_button_style = () => {
  let w = 100
  let h = 100
  return <div>{{ width: `${w}px`, height: `${h}px` }}</div>
}
```

at the end I try to do something like that :

```
function Cell({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => toggle_cell()}
        className="cell"
        // style={button_style}
        style={set_button_style}
        // style={{ width: `${w}px`, height: `${h}px` }}
      >
        {<Img fluid={children.childImageSharp.fluid} />}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you want to return an object with the values supplied? i.e. `const createButtonStyle = (width, height) => ({ width: \`${width}px\`, height: \`${height}px\` })` which you can then use as `let customBtnStyle = createButtonStyle(100, 100); // customBtnStyle = { width: '100px', height: '100px' }`

Comment: Are you trying to set the `style` of a JSX element in terms of specifying `width` and `height`?

Comment: @nbokmans, yep I want return an object and style my button with it. I'm beginner in JS. I improve my post to explaine better.

Comment: @Alexander Staroselky I imprve my post to explain my purpose.

Comment: Well, in `style={set_button_style}`. Are you calling the function `set_button_style` to return the object value? It doesn't look like it. Did you mean `style={set_button_style()}`.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky when I do `style={set_button_style()}` that, my browser return `hot update was not successful` `(AppContainer, in button (at grid_button.js:47)) TypeError: can't convert symbol to string`

Comment: It's not clear which you are specifically trying as `set_button_style` has different outputs, but here is an example in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gljr6u?file=src/App.js

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky that's exactly I try to attemps. thx a lot. I'm very lost with the jsx.

Comment: So are you saying you have updated YOUR code to be exactly what is in the stackblitz example and it's still not working? If so, can you fork that example, update it to match what you have for troubleshooting?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I say with your snippet my code work like a charm. So big hug for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
const set_button_style = () => {
  let w = 100
  let h = 100
  return { width: `${w}px`, height: `${h}px` };
};
```

```
function Cell({ children }) {
  const buttonStyles = set_button_style();
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => toggle_cell()}
        className="cell"
        style={set_button_style}
      >
        {<Img fluid={children.childImageSharp.fluid} />}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gljr6u?file=src/App.js) in action.

Hopefully that helps.